# Can I deduplicate content of zip files on Artifactory side?

Tags: deployment, duplicates, artifactory

I'm using JFrom Artifactory, which has deduplication feature - [see documentation](https://jfrog.com/blog/database-wrong-fud/). Our deployment procedure is the following:

1. Create zip file with libraries: jars, dlls, etc. This is the same with [war file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) or with fat jar.
2. During deployment: just extract content of zip file and do small initialization scripts.

As you understand, the most of content on these files is already on the Artifactory:

1. 3rd party java dependencies are already on the same Artifactory
2. Previous installation has a lot of the same binaries

So, **question**: how can I ask Artifactory to unzip my archives on server side during upload and then transparent zip it back during download?

This solution will give major data deduplication for me, which gain the following advantages:

1. Saving disk space
2. Decreasing server IO

And I know, that there will be the following disadvantages:

1. Checksum of the zip package can be changed
2. CPU load can be increased during artifacts upload and download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is doable transparently from the client side. However, if you are ready to change your clients, I can imagine:

- On the upload / release front, use JFrog CLI and its *--explode* option for uploads.
  The rationale for this flag is at https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go/issues/5 and the feature is quickly described in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles

Instead of uploading simply your ZIP / WAR with any client or JFrog CLI like

```
jfrog rt u my.zip repo-release/test/0.5/my-0.5.zip
```

You would upload it while asking for it to be exploded on the target

```
jfrog rt u  --explode my.zip repo-release/test/0.5/my-0.5.zip/thisisignored.zip
```

- On the download side, use a User Plugin (only available with Pro instances though) to zip the directory content on the fly. There is an existing implementation at https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/download/downloadDirectoryContent that you can install on your Artifactory server.

Once this is set up, you should be able to retrieve your original zip with

```
curl -X GET -uadmin:password "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo-release/test/0.5/my-0.5.zip;downloadDirectory+=true" > my.zip
```

Comment: I fully agree with you.. Moreover, by using Gradle you can modify uploading task. And you shown downloading schema change, however I'd like to see this on the server side. This is quite useful, for example, for Docker storage and for war-files storage.